# how to hide/remove by default progress icon during application running

Tags: blackberry, progress-bar, blackberry-jde

i am working with one BB java Application in OS 5.0. Application have one Screen in which List & Ad banner are place .. Banner is downloading and replacing in specific time interval .. my problem is that when i am on that screen Blackberry by default `Progress icon` are placed .. please tell me how to hide/remove from this screen ..

This happen only in 9700 Simulator and device .. and working properly in 9550 device and simulator.

Please see attachment pic with progress icon.[image]

Thanks in Advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the progress icon when the System garbage collector is working. You will not be able to remove the progress icon as you dont have any control over it. If the garbage collector is working, let it do, as it is trying to free up memory.

The full garbage collection operation executes for 1 second on average and should take less than 2 seconds to complete. The full garbage collection operation performs the following actions:

- It performs a RAM garbage collection operation.
- It marks objects in flash memory that are no longer referenced or no longer persisted.
- It releases any nonpersistent object handles in RAM and flash memory.

The system might initiate a full garbage collection operation in the following situations:

- The BlackBerry® Java® Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because of a lack of available space in RAM.
- A process is about to exceed its currently allocated heap size.
- The BlackBerry JVM cannot allocate a new object because the object handles are not available.
- The BlackBerry device is idle.

This info is from [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5827/Full_garbage_collection_on_a_BB_device_447127_11.jsp)

If your app is in the above situations, the progress icon will be shown. Now you know when it is shown, debug your app in the device, and see which situations apply to you.

Comment: thanx a lot for the knowledge .. App is working fine in my 9550 device . and Simulator have already 136 MB free . what is the instance way to remove this ..

Comment: Free up some memory in your 9700 device and then try

Comment: check this http://crackberry.com/blackberry-101-how-free-memory-your-blackberry-smartphone

Comment: i have resolve this issue.. In my screen there are lots of images for with focus and without focus so i have remove all invalidate and issue is resolve from this device9700.